# How to Solve Error: Call to a member function move() on string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, move

I am uploading an image to a folder and saving data to the database. How can I solve this error? The error is in the following line...

> ```
> $property_features_image->move($destinationPath,$property_features_image);
> ```

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'property_feature' => 'required|unique:property_features,property_features_name',
        'property_icon' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:10240',
    ]);

    $property_features_name = $request->property_feature;
    $property_features_image = $request->file('property_icon');
    $property_features_image = $property_features_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
    $property_features_image->move($destinationPath, $property_features_image);

    DB::table('property_features')->insert([
        'property_features_name' => $property_features_name,
        'property_features_image' => $property_features_image,
    ]);
}
```

**Blade**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{url('/admin/property-features')}}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}" name="_token"/>
        <label for="Property">Add Property Feature</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="property_feature" name="property_feature"
               placeholder="Enter Property Feature">
        <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Property Features's Icon</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="property_icon" name="property_icon">
        <?php echo($errors->first('property_feature', "<li class='ab' style='color:red;'>:message</li>"));?>
        <?php echo($errors->first('property_icon', "<li class='ab' style='color:red;'>:message</li>"));?>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$property_features_image = $property_features_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Assigns `$property_features_image` variable to a string value.
And strings cannot have any methods (you are trying to call move() method).
So removing the line should help, but then you must ensure everything else is ok. The getClientOriginalExtension() might be required somewhere, but we don't see all the code.

Comment: if i remove this , then it save temp name in database and dont upload in folder. temp name is :C:\xampp\tmp\php5DE1.tmp